# Meaning of shake-off in nuclear physics

Tags: nuclear-physics, terminology, definition

What does shake-off mean in nuclear physics?

The word appears, for example, in the title of [this article](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevC.107.045502): "**Shake-off** in the ¹⁶⁴Er neutrinoless double-electron capture and the dark matter puzzle"

Comment: This is a Q&A site, so you're expected to write questions as self-contained as possible. Please don't force people to follow an external link just to understand what you're asking and explain here. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question slightly so that it is not just based on the link.

Comment: The title doesn't say anything. Please provide some *context*, so that people can at least be sure that it isn't a made-up word in this article.

Comment: Well, the paper discusses the mechanism is quite some detail. One summary quote is "The shake-off is a consequence of the very rapid, instantaneous
change in the inner-atomic electrostatic potential VZ (r)
in the initial atom to the potential in the daughter atom"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Shake-off" refers to an electron being ejected from an atom, i.e. ionization.  A related term, "shake-up", refers to an electron being moved to a higher energy state within the atom, i.e. excitation.

This usage is [fairly common](https://www.google.com/search?q=electron+%22shake-off%22+%22shake-up%22), and "shake-off" can be traced back to [Robert Millikan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Andrews_Millikan), who in his 1917 book "The Electron", [states on page 138](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.22792/page/n154/mode/1up?q=shake) :

> We must conclude, then, that an atom has so loose a structure that another atom, if endowed with enough speed, can shoot straight through it without doing anything more than, in some instances, to shake off from that atom an electron or two.